# How can I fix the "Failed to parse source map from ..." errors in my ReactJS/TS project

Tags: reactjs, npm, barcode, react-tsx, npm-package

I have a ReactJS project where I wanted to use a Barcode-Scanner npm module with the name **html5-qrcode**, but I always get this error:

`Failed to parse source map from 'C:\...\node_modules\html5-qrcode\third_party\index.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\node_modules\html5-qrcode\third_party\index.js.map'`

And then there are errors like: (seperated for readability)

**WARNING** `in ./node_modules/html5-qrcode/esm/camera/core-impl.js Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):`

**Failed** `to parse source map from 'C:\...\node_modules\src\camera\core-impl.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\node_modules\src\camera\core-impl.ts'`

I thought it might be an TS error, because every file of the second error part has a .ts ending.
So I made a new ReactTS project with all components and co in it, but I still get the same error.

I thought it might be an TS error, because every file of the second error part has a .ts ending. So I made a new ReactTS project with all components and co in it, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like the npm package has issues with its source maps and webpacks's source-map-loader module is not able to process them. This doesn't really affect the application itself but having all those warnings is annoying.

I came across two solutions: either force the source-map-loader to skip the culprit package or ignore source-map warnings all together.

To achieve either solution, you'll need to be able to override the `webpack.config.js`. How to override it really depends on the framework you use to run your React apps (I have mine setup using NX)

### Solution 1: Ignore source-mapping warnings (Easiest)

Add `ignoreWarnings: [/Failed to parse source map/]` to your webpack configuration.
E.g.

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = (config) => {
  return merge(config, {
    ignoreWarnings: [/Failed to parse source map/]
  });
};
```

Your webpack.config.js will look a lot different than this.
The idea is to add (or override) **ignoreWarnings** with the pattern of the message it should ignore.

### Solution 2: Skip source-map-loading for culprit package (Cleanest?)

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = (config, context) => {
  return merge(config, {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'source-map-loader',
              options: {
                filterSourceMappingUrl: (url, resourcePath) => {
                  // @zxing has issues with its source maps
                  if (/@zxing/i.test(resourcePath)) {
                    return false;
                  }

                  return true;
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

The idea here is to override the source-map-loader rules and skip its execution if the current resource matches the regex. In my case, I want to skip any resource that contains @zxing.

I tried using hte exclude option but I had no luck with that and opted to use the **filterSourceMappingUrl** instead. Maybe it works for you though. Remember, the pathing has to be absolute so you might need to adapt the excluded pathings.
[More details here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/source-map-loader/)

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = (config, context) => {
  return merge(config, {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: ['source-map-loader'],
          exclude:  ['/node_modules/@zxing']
        }
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

1. add `react-app-rewired` to your project:

```
yarn add --dev react-app-rewired
```

or

```
npm install react-app-rewired --save-dev
```

2. modify your `package.json` with those lines:

```
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
```

3. create a file called `config-overrides.js` in project root (same folder as package.json) with this content:

```
module.exports = function override(config) {
  return {
    ...config,
    ignoreWarnings: [
      {
        module: /node_modules\/stylis-plugin-rtl/,
      },
    ],
  }
}
```

4. change "stylis-plugin-rtl" in `config-overrides.js` above to whichever name of library that has an invalid build and throwing errors.
5. source maps errors should no longer appear.